# 99 Bottles of beer on the wall using boolean method

Tags: c++, methods, boolean

Hello I am attempting to pull this cout dialouge from this bool method.I want to be able to get input the initial number of bottles, then call the boolean method that will determine whether it is in the range or not. If it is true it will return the dialogue in the boolean method, if not it will ask user to input the amount again. Below is what I have so far, but I am extremely confused.

```
bool bottleAmount(int amount); // function prototype

int main()

{
int amount = 0;
cout << "How many bottles of beer on the wall? ";
cin >> amount;

bottleAmount(amount);
return 0; 

}

       bool bottleAmount(int amount)
{
bool status;

if (amount >= 2)
    status = true;
{
    for (amount; amount > 0 && amount < 101; amount -= 1)
    {
        cout << amount << " bottles of beer on the wall\n"
            << amount << " bottles of beer\n"
            << "Take 1 down, pass it around\n"
            << amount - 1 << " bottles of beer on the wall\n\n";
}
        if (amount < 2)
        status =  false;
{
        cout << "invalid value";
}
}
```

Comment: Your `bottleAmount()` function doesn't return on all paths. This is undefined behavior. You should see a warning for this when you compile. Don't ignore compiler warnings!

Comment: A function that returns a `bool` must return a value always. Your `if (bottles > 2)` branch does not return a value at all if the test is true. Your `main` does nothing with the return value of the function in any case, so it may as well not return one. Pick one - you're either going to use the return value and make sure that the function always returns one, or you're going to change the function to not return a value and do the testing in that function.

Comment: So would i need to insert the prompt in the bool instead? This way the value would be given by the user and tested before making it to main, or am i still missing something?

Comment: The test should be in `main`, and should be in a loop that tests the value, calls `bottleAmount` if the value input is valid or loops again until it is, and the `bottleAmount` doesn't need to return anything. But why does the value have to be > 2? Why wouldn't *1 bottle of beer on the wall* be an invalid starting point?

Comment: Have you tried [having your program reviewed by your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: That was the way the assignment was worded, but im not exactly sure why. Also, im still not understand what im supposed to do here. Im thinking in main the user inputs the starting bottle amount, then the bool is called. In the bool if the value is greater than or equal to 2 run the prompt until the amount reaches 0, subtracting one each time.

Comment: No i have never used rubber duck

Comment: Maybe you should try giving your rubber duck an opportunity to explain what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

This can certainly be done much better using a void function (a function that does not return a value). You might want to change the fact that somehow `amount` turns into `bottles` and the computer is supposed to know that without copying the value to `bottles`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bottleAmount(int amount); // function prototype

    int main()
        
        {
               int amount = 0; // initialize to zero
               cout << "How many bottles of beer on the wall? ";
               cin >> amount;
        
               bottleAmount(amount);
               return 0; // generally it is a good idea to properly end a program
           
        }
    
    void bottleAmount(int amount)
    {
     if (amount >= 2) 
            {
                cout << amount << " bottle(s) of beer on the wall\n"
                    << amount << " bottle(s) of beer\n"
                    << "Take 1 down, pass it around\n"
                    << amount - 1 << " bottle(s) of beer on the wall\n\n";
            }
     else 
            {
                cout << amount << " bottle of beer on the wall\n"
                    << amount << " bottle of beer\n"
                    << "Take 1 down, pass it around\n"
                    << "No more bottles of beer on the wall\n";
            }
    }
```

Comment: This helps a lot cause i see where i messed up in main. Although i still need to figure out how to make it a bool, i see this is the reason i was running into issues

Comment: I tweaked it to this, but im still getting an error message

Comment: If that is the case I would not make the function return a bool unless your assignment says you need to. I would keep the function `bottle amount` void, but have boolean logic inside of the function. There are many issues with your original code, but do you understand that when you name the function `bool bottleAmount();` bool is supposed to be the return type? As in the bool value is returned back to the function call? I suggest referencing a good book or site. It can become pretty time consuming to ask SO every single assignment question you have.

Comment: Why are you doing homework for someone else?

Comment: I understand now thank you for explaining. Also this was just an assignment from last year that I am doing for practice to understand some basics again. I did an easier version yesterday and still had trouble with it.

Comment: At least rate me as the most helpful answer for doing your homework for you XD